# How can I find the parent tr of a td using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
    tdToPad = tds.filter('[id^="input_Title_"]')
    pad = 60;
    tdToPad.css('margin-left', pad);
```

What I would like to do is to remove any class that starts with "X-" and give the row that is contained by "tdToPad" a class of "X-" + pad.

Something like:

```
<tr class='X-60'>
   <td>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Being that toToPad refers to the td element in a row. How can I give the parent tr the class "X-" + pad ? I think I need something like the following but if that's the correct way to do it then how can I remove elements already there with a class of "X-" somevalue and then give this element the correct class?

```
tdToPad.Parent('tr')
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method:

> Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

```
tdToPad.closest('tr')
       .addClass('X-' + pad)
```

**update:**

```
tdToPad.closest('tr').get(0).className = tdToPad.closest('tr').get(0).className.replace(/\bX\-.*?\b/g, '');
tdToPad.closest('tr').addClass('X-' + pad)
```

Comment: There may already be a class there with "X-" followed by a number. Is there a way I could remove this before adding the new class?

Comment: @Gemma yes, you can remove the class and then add another one, try the updated answer.

Comment: thanks but how can I remove just classes that have "X-" at the start of their names? In your example you just put the class name 'class". What I have is that the class could be anything starting with "X-" and there may or may not already be one there. I just want to replace with the latest. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You're almost right. Just use the correct spelling for `parent()` ([docu](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)) and add a `addClass()` ([docu](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)) call to it.

```
tdToPad.parent('tr').addClass( 'X-' + pad );
```

Comment: Is it better to use parent or closest? Can I remove any classes already there which start with X- ?